Handle multiple date fields enable disable corresponding input
I need to fix this method so that it is one method that handles multiple input date fields to enable the corresponding input when date "FROM" is selected and date "TO" is enabled.
I attempted to use formGroup and use formControlName to now avail
HTML example
<div class="display-flex flex-row width-full flex-align-end flex-row-override-480">
    <div class="width-half inline-input">
        <hvcore-form-field-date [dateMax]="dateMax | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [formGroup]="formGroup" formControlName="receiveDateFrom" class=""
label="Recipient Date:"></hvcore-form-field-date>
    </div>
    <span class="usa-label usa-label-inline margin-right-3 margin-left-3">To:</span>
    <div class="width-half inline-input">
        <hvcore-form-field-date [dateMax]="dateMax | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [formGroup]="formGroup" formControlName="receiveDateTo" class="" label=""></hvcore-form-field-date>
    </div>
</div>
        
<div class="display-flex flex-row width-full flex-align-end flex-row-override-480">
    <div class="width-half inline-input">
        <hvcore-form-field-date [dateMax]="dateMax | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [formGroup]="formGroup" formControlName="caseStatusDateFrom" class="" label="Status Date:" (change)="setStatusDate(formControlName.value)"></hvcore-form-field-date>
    </div>
    <span class="usa-label usa-label-inline margin-right-3 margin-left-3">To:</span>
    <div class="width-half inline-input">
        <hvcore-form-field-date [dateMax]="dateMax | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [formGroup]="formGroup" formControlName="caseStatusDateTo" class="" label=""></hvcore-form-field-date>
    </div>
</div>

TS Example
public setStatusDate($event: Event) {
    debugger;
    const disableEnableOptions = { emitEvent: true };
    const caseStatusDateFrom = this.formGroup.get("caseStatusDateFrom");
    const caseStatusDateTo = this.formGroup.get("caseStatusDateTo");
    caseStatusDateFrom?.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
        debugger;
        $event;
        if (value === "") {
            caseStatusDateTo?.disable(disableEnableOptions);
            caseStatusDateTo?.setValue(caseStatusDateFrom?.value)
        }
   
        else {
            caseStatusDateTo?.enable(disableEnableOptions);
    
            if (caseStatusDateTo?.value !== "" && caseStatusDateTo?.value < caseStatusDateFrom?.value) {
                caseStatusDateTo?.setValue(caseStatusDateFrom?.value);
            }
        }
    })
}


onDateChange($event: Event, toInput: string, fromInput: string) {
    $event;
    const disableEnableOptions = { emitEvent: true };
    const dateFrom = this.formGroup.get(fromInput);
    const dateTo = this.formGroup.get(toInput);
    // this.dateMin = dateFrom?.value as Date;
      if (dateFrom?.value === "") {
        dateTo?.disable(disableEnableOptions);
        dateTo?.setValue(dateFrom?.value)
      } else {
        dateTo?.enable(disableEnableOptions);
        // if (dateTo?.value!== "" && this.dateMax < this.dateMin) {
        //   dateTo?.setValue(dateFrom?.value);
        // }
      }
    }


You can use a method utilizing valueChanges property in observable of the FROM date field to handle enabling or disabling the TO field.
If the FROM date is empty, disable the TO field.
If it is selected, enable the TO field, and make sure that if TO is earlier than FROM, it is adjusted.
Refer to the sample code below along with the TS method.
Sample HTML :
<div class="display-flex flex-row width-full flex-align-end flex-row-override-480">
    <div class="width-half inline-input">
        <hvcore-form-field-date [dateMax]="dateMax | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [formGroup]="formGroup" formControlName="receiveDateFrom" 
            label="Recipient Date:" (change)="setDateFields('receiveDateFrom', 'receiveDateTo')">
        </hvcore-form-field-date>
    </div>
    <span class="usa-label usa-label-inline margin-right-3 margin-left-3">To:</span>
    <div class="width-half inline-input">
        <hvcore-form-field-date [dateMax]="dateMax | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [formGroup]="formGroup" formControlName="receiveDateTo" 
            label="">
        </hvcore-form-field-date>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="display-flex flex-row width-full flex-align-end flex-row-override-480">
    <div class="width-half inline-input">
        <hvcore-form-field-date [dateMax]="dateMax | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [formGroup]="formGroup" formControlName="caseStatusDateFrom" 
            label="Status Date:" (change)="setDateFields('caseStatusDateFrom', 'caseStatusDateTo')">
        </hvcore-form-field-date>
    </div>
    <span class="usa-label usa-label-inline margin-right-3 margin-left-3">To:</span>
    <div class="width-half inline-input">
        <hvcore-form-field-date [dateMax]="dateMax | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" [formGroup]="formGroup" formControlName="caseStatusDateTo" 
            label="">
        </hvcore-form-field-date>
    </div>
</div>

Sample TS method:
public setDateFields(fromControlName: string, toControlName: string) {
    const fromControl = this.formGroup.get(fromControlName);
    const toControl = this.formGroup.get(toControlName);

    
    fromControl?.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {  // watch for changes to the FROM date field
        const disableEnableOptions = { emitEvent: false };

        
        if (!value) { // If the FROM date is empty, disable the 'TO' field and set its value to match FROM if necessary
            toControl?.disable(disableEnableOptions);
            toControl?.setValue(null);  // Optionally reset the 'TO' date value
        } else {
            toControl?.enable(disableEnableOptions);                    
            if (toControl?.value && toControl?.value < value) { // If TO date is set and it's earlier than FROM, update it to match the FROM date
                toControl?.setValue(value);
            }
        }
    });
}


I think this is close. I was able to pull this off like this. Answer will be added below:

Thanks appreciate if you can mark the answer as correct or give an upvote for the sake contribute TIA :-)

why on earth you add to each input the "formGroup"? Enclose the inputs between a <form [formGroup]="formGroup"> and remove these from tag input. NOTE: in general, to disable a formControl we can use a directive, see, e.g. this SO
